# Face fill not working

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces, shortcut

Hitting F repeatedly has stopped working. It makes the first face but then doesn't keep making faces like it usually would. Specifics as follows:

I have a a closed loop with a lot of vertices that I want to fill. As you can see here:[image]

For this particular situation I don't want to use a grid fill. So in edit mode I picked some vertices and hit F to make a face. then I moved into edge select and selected three edges like so:

[image]

And hit F again and it created a face.

[image]

So far so good. But then I would usually hit F repeatedly and it would keep adding faces one after the other. but I hit F again and again and nothing happens.

I've tried starting with vertices in different amounts (from 3 up to about 10) to create the first face, moving the first face to different areas, once selecting one edge (the long outside edge),trying F in face, edge and vertex mode and nothing is working. Any idea why? Its always worked for me before so I'm stumped. I have a lot of these to do so if I have to select edges manually to make each face I'll be here for days.

Thanks!

ADDITION: to be clear I have tried this with one edge/ two verts selected (see images below) and F still doesn't work.

Here is the file if anyone wants to have a look: [L hotkey not working blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar4Sov07HW22gUSSI1h_iWOKJmOG?e=qDtZtn)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

as you can see in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YTHgrxFBDs you can either use vertex select or edge select mode.

After you inserted the first face,

1. in vertex select mode just select the two vertices where you want to add the faces to like this:

[image]

2. or in edge mode just select the one edge where you want to add the faces to like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi yes, I tried both of those and neither are working. any idea why?

Comment: if both do not work, i would recommend making a video and providing a link to that video of your full (!) Blender window so we can see what you are doing. Even better if you turn on screencast keys (free add-on) so we can see what you are typing. Then i think we have a very good chance to help you. Else we can just guess - and i hate guessing because mostly it is a waste of time

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you have overlapping vertices, to fix it select all (<kbd>A</kbd>), press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.

Repeat <kbd>F</kbd> will work if you select one edge with 2 vertices, don't select the 2 edges on the side:

[image]

Your object:

[image]

Comment: yeah I tried that in edge mode (one edge selected) and vertex mode (two verts selected) as you have indicated here and it doesn't work. I hit F and nothing happens. any idea why?

Comment: If you have an old version of Blender you need to activate an addon (was it F2?), but in the latest version you shouldn't have anything to activate, but maybe share your file?

Comment: I'm using latest version of blender (3.5) and have the F2 addon activated (although the F function was working both before and after I activated F2 and only on this file its stopped working.) I'll try sharing the file. Thanks!

Comment: file is here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar4Sov07HW22gUSSI1h_iWOKJmOG?e=qDtZtn

Comment: You have overlapping vertices, select all, press M > Merge by Distance

Comment: Ok thanks done that and 66 verts removed (I had auto merge on so its strange that they weren't auto merged but anyways) buuuuutttttt..... F still not working

Comment: 828 vertices are removed if you select all and merge, and it works fine for me

Comment: yeah that didn't work for me (there was only approx 1100 verts to begin, any larger merge would loose detail) BUTit its solved. Went into Preferences and restored factory settings and F worked! Something went wrong with my keymap at some point it seems. Lloaded my old settings again and went into the keymap to try and figure out exactly what - but I couldn't find anything out of the ordinary so it is very strange. so I've gone back to factory settings and then reactivated all my add ons and now its working fine. I still don't know what triggered it to stop working but glad its  working again.

Comment: thanks so much for your suggestions :-)

Comment: OK that's weird but great if you've fixed it